# How to configure SSL for exist-db in Jetty with letsencrypt CA signed certificate

Tags: exist-db

I want to configure letsencrypt ca signed certificate for my exist-db app and I have used the below two guides but could not succeed.

https://www.cirt.gov.bd/a-step-by-step-guide-to-securing-a-tomcat-server-with-letsencrypt-ssl-certificate/
[How to configure SSL in Jetty with CA signed certificate properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41758983/how-to-configure-ssl-in-jetty-with-ca-signed-certificate-properly/67277339#67277339)

Can anyone help me to dig out the issue?

Comment: i am getting the error
java.io.IOException: keystore password was incorrect

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to run your existdb instance behind a nginx proxy and let  nginx handle SSL connections with letsencrypt certs.

More on existdb deployment scenarios here:

https://e-editiones.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/Common-eXist-db-TEI-Publisher-Deployment-Scenarios.pdf